# C#, Looping through dataset and show each record from a dataset column

Tags: c#, foreach, dataset

In C#, I'm trying to loop through my dataset to show data from each row from a specific column.  I want the get each date under the column name "TaskStart" and display it on a report, but its just shows the date from the first row for all rows can anybody help?

```
 foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
 {

     foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
     {
         DateTime TaskStart = DateTime.Parse(
             ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TaskStart"].ToString());
         TaskStart.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
         rpt.SetParameterValue("TaskStartDate", TaskStart);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
DateTime TaskStart = DateTime.Parse(dr["TaskStart"].ToString());
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, now its just showing the last date on the last row for all records?

Comment: It looks like you have issue with your rpt.SetParameterValue("TaskStartDate", TaskStart);
because you setting it at each lap but you use it elswhere outside of it. Also your formatted date doesn't go anywhere as well.

Answer (score 24):

I believe you intended it more this way:

```
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        DateTime TaskStart = DateTime.Parse(dr["TaskStart"].ToString());
        TaskStart.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
        rpt.SetParameterValue("TaskStartDate", TaskStart);
    }
}
```

You always accessed your first row in your dataset.

Answer (score 9):

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        var ParentId=dr["ParentId"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (DataRow table in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
                int ForType = Convert.ToInt32(table["Fortype"].ToString());
                ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "ForType ='" + ForType +"'";
                rbtnQuestion.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                rbtnQuestion.DataBind();

        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).